# Is there any evidence of relativity in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, science

In the comments on [How is age kept track of in the Star Wars universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168303/how-is-age-kept-track-of-in-the-star-wars-universe) we started discussing the relevance of relativity in the star wars universe.

**Is there any evidence in Canon or Legends of any relativistic effects (in particular time dilation) being relevant in the Star Wars universe?**

---

<sub>*Please indicate which parts of your answer are Legends or current (Disney) canon.*</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relativity at high speed exists within Legends but is hand-waved through the use of [relativistic shielding](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Relativistic_shield)

> *WOZIN, DELEMEDE - To look at him, you'd swear he wasn't a day over 35
>   standard years old, but Bosbit Matarcher's birth records confirm the
>   unthinkable - he's 225 years old. His secret? Faulty relativistic
>   shielding. "I got what I thought was a deal on this ship," says
>   Matarcher, pointing to his antique Delemedian starhopper. "I engaged
>   the jump drive for a trip in outsystem. It took about two hours. When
>   I got out, it was 200 years later." Matarcher is taking it all in
>   stride. "Well, truth to tell, when I left, home was pretty shoddy and
>   run down, but now Delemede is a thriving place. I can't wait to get
>   back, but this time I'll fly transit."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Holonet Article: 225-year Old Man's Secret? Time Dilation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130728111154/http://www.holonetnews.com/48/life/13321_2.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ignoring the fact that employing the theory of relativity with regards to FTL travel is in itself ridiculous, if you travelled faster than light in a ship without (or with faulty) "relativistic shielding", wouldn't you end up going _back_ in time, not forwards?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo FTL travel in the SW universe uses hyperspace, which is (as best I understand it) an alternate dimension in which distance is condensed. By jumping into hyperspace, crossing some distance, and then exiting hyperspace back into realspace, you could move from A to B in less time than it would take for light to cross that distance directly, without actually exceeding the speed of light.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo, FTL travel doesn't inherently take you backwards in time, unless you're a Star Trek character I guess.  It's difficult to change physics to allow FTL travel without it also allowing time travel, but in-universe you'd still have a choice whether to go backwards or forwards or neither.  What really doesn't make sense about "faulty relativistic shielding" is that by all rights it should affect how much time the trip takes *from your perspective*, not from the perspective of the outside universe.